# PowerPivot Relationship Made But Formula Not Working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerpivot

I have 2 tables. Relationship is made on campaignID

Table 1 >>Clicks
- clickID 
- campaignID
- other_stuff

Table 2 - Campaigns
- campaignID
- campaign_name
- campaign_cpc

I created a calculated field on the clicks table where i count the number of clickID.

However when i try to create a calculated field which does:

`Clicks[count of clickID]*Campaigns[campaign_cpc]`

I get an error. Is says it needs a relationship. More specifically:

*"The value for column 'campaign_cpc' in table 'Campaigns' cannot be determined in the current context"*

I already tried using the RELATED() function but it still doesn't work. I get the same error.

I've been at this problem for the past day and would appreciate some guidance. 
Thanks

Comment: WOW. After writing this out, i figured it out. I had to go into the Campaigns table within Powerpivot, then create a column pointing to the "count of clickID". Then i was able to run the proper calculation!

Answer (score 0):

So here's the setup for anyone who is having this issue:

**Table 1 -Clicks**
- clickID 
- campaignID
- count_of_clickID

**Table 2 - Campaigns**
- campaignID
- campaign_name
- campaign_cpc
- total_views (points to the count_of_clickID column)

Then after this, i was able to run my original calculation :)